# Yup and Formik usage .match()

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

password: Yup.string().required('Please Enter your password').matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/, 'test').required("Password is required"),

anyone here know why .matches will not bring back an error message? i really dont want to run a bunch of .test() for each criteria we want met.

seems this is an ongoing issue with Yup and the work arounds are not making sense to how we set it up in our code

i get the required message back fine but i want the message in the .match() to show if its not met

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: { username: '', password: '', firstName: '', lastName: '' },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
        dispatch(checkLogin({
            username: values.username,
            password: values.password
        }, async () => {
            return await router.push("/");
        }));
        setSubmitted(true);
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
        username: Yup.string().email("Must be a valid email").required("Email is 
 required"),
        password: Yup.string().required('Please Enter your password').matches(/^(? 
 =.*\\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/, 'test').required("Password is 
 required"),
        firstName: Yup.string().matches(/^([^0-9]*)$/).required("First name is 
 required"),
        lasstName: Yup.string().matches(/^([^0-9]*)$/).required("First name if 
 required")

    }),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It turns out your regex has some unwanted spacing. Remove it and it should work.**

You have two required checks, try to remove one and it should work

```
password: Yup.string()
   .required('Please Enter your password')
   .matches(/^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/, 'test')
```

Also, it seems like you need to add the `.shape` https://github.com/jquense/yup#objectshapefields-object-nosortedges-arraystring-string-schema

```
Yup.object().shape({})
```